# Return Outer Apply Results as a new Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query with an outer apply, that 90% of the time will return null. However for that other 10% of the time, I want to return it as another row. I was debating on doing this as a union, but then I was curious if it could be handled any other way.

```
Select d1.name
,d2.name
,d3.name
,b.name2
,b.name3

from database1 d1
inner join database2 d2 on d1.d2_id = d2.id
inner join database3 d3 on d2.d3_id = d3.id

outer apply(select d2a.name2
            ,d3.name3

            from database1 d1a
            inner join database2 d2a on d1a.d2a_id = d2a.id
            inner join database3 d3a on d2a.d3a_id = d3a.id
            where 1=1
            and d1a.id = d1.id
            and (d2a.name<>d2.name and d3a.name <> d3.name)
            )b

where 1=1


Result set now
d1.name|d2.name|d3.name|b.name2|b.name3
1          1        1       2      2
```

Result Set Wanted

```
d1.name|d2.name|d3.name
1          1       1
1          2       2
```

Comment: what happened to b.name2 and 3?

Comment: They got bumped to the new row and dropped as columns

Comment: i reckon just use union...